# Unity3d Project In App Purchases update yields errors

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to update a Unity project that was built in version 2019.4.01f (Intel, LTS) to version 2021.3.10f (Apple Silicon, LTS). The reason is that I need update the In App Purchases package from Unity because Google Play requires that I update the billing library.

I already tried a bunch of options, but I keep getting errors. If I generate the GoogleTangle I get  `error CS0103: The name 'Obfuscator' does not exist in the current context`. If I don't generate new tangles or copy the old tangles from the old path to the new one (according to the steps from [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityIAPSettingUp.html)), I get other errors like:  `error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Purchasing' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine' (are you missing an assembly reference?)` and other similar errors. If I manually add some of the Purchasing assembly definitions I see no improvements.

Did anyone tried doing this recently?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error was an Assembly definition. In order to allow PlayMode tests access to some of the game code I had an Assembly Definition in Assets/Scripts that was referenced in the PlayMode Assembly.
After removing the tests and the Assembly definition, the errors went away except for a new one that lets you know that you need to initialise Unity Services before initialising Purchasing (that's how Unity Purchasing works now).

This was a quick fix. The correct solution would be to keep the tests and use Assembly definitions in the folders that contain the code that PlayMode tests need to access. That will most probably lead to the need of Assembly definitions in other folders as well and at this point the code structure must be built in such a way that you don't get cyclic references between Assembly definitions.